# FCM Handshake Exception from a network

Tags: java, ssl, networking, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to access https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send from a Web Application in Java. The problem is I receive the following exception while trying to access it:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This happens only when I try to access it from a specific network (eg. Work). From other networks (eg. Home), I do not see this issue.

What type of changes would I need to do (in the network) so as to I would be able to access the url from the Work Network too.

Comment: This could be an issue with your intranet DNS.
To test this try to set the DNS to 8.8.8.8 and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Diego. Issue got resolved after changes in the network configurations. Basically the firewall had been blocking the request.

Comment: Also this can be caused by web debugging proxies like Fiddler or Charles.