# Push to Google FCM occasionally gives error with SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, firebase, spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am  getting the following error occasionally in production. We are unable to reproduce this error in non production env. Any idea why this is occurring. We are using Apache HTTP client Spring boot.

"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send":Received fatal alert: decrypt_error; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: decrypt_error

Comment: possibe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212944/fcm-handshake-exception-from-a-network

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I believe that is a different issues.

Comment: Hi, @VijayRam please were you able to fix this? If so how :pray:

Comment: It was 3 yrs ago. I could not recollect what we did. My bad, I did not update this thread with the what we found. I will see if i have any documentation around that. @Enoobong

Comment: Thanks, Vijay! Please me know

Comment: I could not find any docs on this from my side. Sorry